# lxsession-default tasks broken

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxsession

Using Lubuntu.

When I hit Ctrl-Alt-Del, it logs me out to the login screen.  It's supposed to bring up the task manager.

Turns out that "lxsession-default tasks" is the problem.

I searched, and there is almost nothing on the web about this command.

In Preference -> default apps for LXsession, I have set the default to Task Manager.  But somehow it's not working.

Disgusting really.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, LXDE.

**Temporary solution:**

Edit  ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

Find the entry that invokes "task manager", change the command from "lxsession-default tasks" to simply "lxtask".

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try installing `qps` (qt process manager)?

```
sudo apt-get install qps
```

Now <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> should work.